# How to find all char strings in a file using python regexs

Tags: python, regex

I have a `.CPP` file with 2 types of strings

`CHAR` strings are characterized by the fact that they appear simply within quotation marks.

`WCHAR` strings are characterized by the fact that they appear in quotation marks preceded by the letter `L`

Example of String CHAR:
`"char string"`

Example of String WCHAR:
`L"wchar string"`

I want to find all the `CHAR`'s in the file (and only them) and then find all the `WCHAR`'s in the file (and only them)

This is the code I currently have. He knows how to find the string between quotes:

```
import re
#find all strings between ""
re.findall('"([^"]*)"', f.read())

#find all strings between L""
re.findall('L"([^"]*)"', f.read())
```

How do I tell him to bring me only the strings between quotation marks as long as there is no letter `L` before the first letter?

here is an example file:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{   
    printf(L"very long first wchar\
    cuple of line\
    string");

    printf("regular char string");

    printf(L" wchar short string in bracket");

    printf("short string in bracket");

    printf("very long\
    cuple of line\
    string");


    printf(L"very long wchar\
    cuple of line\
    string");
}
```

Comment: 1) `r'(?<!L)"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'` 2) `r'L"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'`. But a more appropriate can be 1) `r'(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"(?<!L")([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'` 2) `r'(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*L"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'`.

Comment: He confuses these lines with this REGEX:
`printf ("regular char string");

printf (L"wchar short string in bracket");

printf ("short string in bracket");`
He will not read well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(L)?"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'
```

and append the match to a CHAR type string if Group 1 is *None*, else the string matched is of WCHAR type and you can grab Group 2 value.

**Details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL modifier to let `.` match any char
- `(?<!\\)` - a location that is not preceded with `\`
- `(?:\\\\)*` - zero or more consecutive double backslashes (to avoid matching an escaped quote after a literal backslash)
- `(L)?` - Group 1: an optional `L`
- `"` - a  double quote
- `([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^"\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than a backslash and `"`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - 0+ consecutive occurrences of

    - `\\.` - any char escaped with backslash
    - `[^"\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than a backslash and `"`
- `"` - a closing double quote.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZWHrZ/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Thnblc):

```
import re
rx = r'''(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(L)?"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'''
s = ("#include <stdio.h>\n\n\n"
    "int main()\n"
    "{       \n"
    "    printf(\"regular char string\");\n\n"
    "    printf(L\" wchar short string in bracket\");\n\n"
    "    printf(\"short string in bracket\");\n\n"
    "    printf(\"very long\\\n"
    "    cuple of line\\\n"
    "    string\");\n\n\n"
    "    printf(L\"very long wchar\\\n"
    "    cuple of line\\\n"
    "    string\");\n"
    "}")
chars_list = []
wchars_list = []
for m in re.finditer(rx, s):
    if m.group(1):
        wchars_list.append(m.group(2))
        print("WCHAR: {}".format(m.group(2)))
    else:
        chars_list.append(m.group(2))
        print("CHAR: {}".format(m.group(2)))
```

Output:

```
CHAR: regular char string
WCHAR:  wchar short string in bracket
CHAR: short string in bracket
CHAR: very long\
    cuple of line\
    string
WCHAR: very long wchar\
    cuple of line\
    string
```

Comment: Thank you i try it til now with re.find and it's went seriously rung....